Onto group actions and symmetries.
I was trying to explain informally to someone how group actions encode symmetries of an object $X$. In general the data of a group action is a group homomorphism $f:G \to \text{Aut(X)}$, and just take $\text{Aut(X)}$ to be the collection of automorphisms of $X$ in whatever category you want.
In the concrete case where the automorphisms are bijections with additional structure it really makes sense to think of $G$ as encoding the symmetries of $X$. As I was explaining they asked me what it meant for $f$ to surject, and I told them that this would mean that $G$ is able to witness every symmetry of $X$, and then I told them that in the language they've seen in lecture that meant that $G$ acts transitively.
With some thought I realized that this isn't actually the case, and transitive group actions don't need to be surjections $G \to \text{Aut(X)}$. I started reading back through my notes, then eventually google searching for what we called a group action that surjects onto $\text{Aut(X)}$, but it doesn't seem to have a name. I suppose my question is two-fold:

Firstly, if there is a term, please let me know.
If there isn't, why not? It would seem like $G$ witnessing all symmetries of $X$ is an interesting enough idea to merit a name. I mean we call the action faithful if $f$ is injective. Why isn't this an interesting enough occurance to merit some term?

Perhaps this is completely uninteresting, and any surjection $G$ to $\text{Aut(X)}$ must be silly, I apologize if that's the case. Thanks in advance.


If we have a surjection from $G$ to $\text{Aut}(X)$, then we can just say $G$ is the group of automorphisms of $X$. Indeed, if the action is faithful, then the group $G$ is exactly (up to isomorphism) the group of automorphisms of $X$. Instead, if the action is not faithful, then we are saying there are elements of $G$ that are acting on $X$ just as the identity. Hence we are taking in some sense a group too large
than a group that could encode the symmetries of $X$. In this case,
we usually replace this group  by $G/\ker(f)$ so that the action
becomes faithful, and if the map $f$ is surjective, then this group
is the group of automorphisms of $X$.
As explained above, I think there is no word for this because in that case we can consider $G$ as the  group of automorphisms of $X$ directly, up to isomorphism.

Let me know if this can be a good reason. Or maybe I am wrong and it could exists a name.

I think this is right.

The idea of the group being "too large" to "interestingly" encode the symmetries of $X$ is nice. Thank you.

Thank you very much . Then, if you want, you can verify my answer.

Not sure if it helps, but I came to this while I also asked myself about the meaning (and possible applications) of "surjective actions". Let $C_q$ be the cyclic group of odd prime order $q$ (in multiplicative notation). Then:

Lemma. $\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)$ acts regularly on $C_q\setminus\{1\}$.
Proof. If a group $G$ acts on $C_q$ by automorphisms, then there is a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)$, and $\operatorname{Fix}(g)\le C_q$ for every $g\in G$ (in fact, for $x,y\in \operatorname{Fix}(g)$, $\varphi_g(xy^{-1})=$ $\varphi_g(x)\varphi_g(y)^{-1}=$ $xy^{-1}$, whence $xy^{-1}\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)$). Therefore:
$$\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=k+(|G|-k)q \tag1$$
for some $k\in\{0,\dots,|G|\}$. Now, $|G|-k$ is the number of $g\in G$ such that $\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=q$, namely the number of $g\in G$ such that $\varphi_g(x)=x$ for every $x\in C_q$, namely the number of $g\in G$ such that $\varphi_g=\operatorname{id}_{C_q}$, whence:
$$|G|-k=\left|\operatorname{ker}\varphi\right| \tag2$$
So, if $\varphi$ is injective, then:
$$\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=|G|-1+q \tag3$$
and hence:
$$\text{# of orbits}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|=1+\frac{q-1}{|G|} \tag4$$
Now, if $\varphi$ is also surjective, namely $G\stackrel{\varphi}{\cong}\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)$, then $|G|=q-1$, and so from $(4)$:
$$\text{# of orbits}=2 \tag5$$
Therefore, $C_q=\{1,x,\dots,x^{q-1}\}$ splits into $\{1\}$ (because $\varphi_g(1)=1$ for every $g\in G$) and $\{x,\dots,x^{q-1}\}$. $\space\Box$

